# Background image transition SP2013 - is it possible?

Tags: 2013, css, branding

We are attempting to use SP2013 as our corporate external website and are required to have a homepage that has a transitioning background image. Simple enough for a 'normal' website but successful implementation is proving way too elusive using SP.

The images only need to be visible on the homepage so we have tried using custom page layouts for this but cannot get the images and content displaying at the same time - either get the images displaying and transitioning as required but obscuring everything else or we get the content displayed correctly with all the images stacked below.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in 2010 so assume it is possible in 2013.

In my case I used a CQWP to get the images from a library and then used jQuery to rotate through the images and set them to the background image of the containing DIV.  I then used z-index to ensure my content was positioned over the top of the background image.

Hope this helps.